# How to detect the finish with file_put_contents() in php?

Tags: php, file, detect

In PHP, i will write (create) the file using `file_put_contents($filename, $data);`
It is ok, but i want to detect the finish event of process.

Currently, the page is showing loading status.
This is currently the way i can know it is finish or not.

I want to detect with the code.

Comment: probably duplicate.. maybe this link is useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/21842519/4519636

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a blocking, I/O call, so it finishes when the function call returns.  The return value is the number of bytes written (upon success).

Comment: Ok now i see that 'file_put_contents()' returns the file size, at finish. 
Additionally, can i detect the size 'before' ??
I used: 'file_get_contents()'. If so, i can detect if the process is success writing the all bytes (or) not.

Comment: Size of file (before or after) can be determined by calling `filesize()`

Comment: It don't work.. I used <code>$file = file_get_contents($path)</code> and then <code>echo "Size to Write: ".filesize($file)</code>

Comment: Read the documentation for `filesize()`.  It expects the path to a file, not the contents of a file.  http://us3.php.net/filesize

Comment: uh, i'm supposed to get from URLs (download) .. But "filesize()" don't work with URL(s).. ;(

Comment: Sorry, your original question didn't mention anything about the file being a **remote** resource.  Perhaps you want to revise your original question to make it more accurate what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes yes, i'm SORRY! Please (everyone!) kindly jump to my new thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/6085524/753726

Comment: @AJ: btw, how did you typed the comment text to show formatted <code></code> blocks?

Comment: @Alvin: FYI for future reference, you can edit your original question; there's no need for a new one :)  For code, use backtick marks (`) around the code.

Answer (score 6):

It puts everything on hold until it's over

So you could use something like this to determine when it has finished writing the file.

```
echo "The file's contents are now being written, please wait.";
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
echo "The file's contents have been written.";
```

Answer (score 3):

Retrieve the `Content-Length` header from the remote location first. You can use [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) to do that. Like so:

```
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
echo "To download: " . $headers['Content-Length'] . " bytes.<br />";
```

Comment: Will this always work? Or is there cases were the web application or server refuses to give you just the headers? Also does the get_headers method send HEAD or GET?

Comment: I don't think that the server can refuse to send headers for something. And from the page: "If anyone is curious, as I was, this function does not send a HEAD verb. Instead it sends a GET. Which in my case is not ideal because I need a quick way to get a HTTP status (200, 404, etc.) The problem with GET is that, for cases such as mine, I do not want all the overhead with the data that comes back."

Comment: Alright, so that means it has to download the file anyway then when using get_headers since it's a GET?

Comment: @Ancide: No, it cancels after it gets the headers. (By "overhead", the person meant "the rest of the headers", I believe.)

Comment: $headers['Content-Length'] is not always returns the "string". Sometime it comes with Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 19342374 ). So, we have to handle it. I handle like: gettype($headers['Content-Length'])=="array"

Comment: @minitech I tested this out with a custom socket solution using HEAD instead of GET and it's just like you said, "overhead" == "the rest of the headers". Just wanted to let everyone know for sure :)