# How to detect the size of file, before download (while remote downloading)?

Tags: php, download, filesize, content-length

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect the finish with file_put_contents() in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085357/how-to-detect-the-finish-with-file-put-contents-in-php)

I'm making a download script in PHP. Like following:

```
1) $item = file_get_contents($url);
2) echo "To download: ".filesize($url)."<br>";
3) echo "Received: ".file_put_contents("Downloaded_File_Name", $item);
```

Downloading works fine (I receive the file) but line 2 doesn't work.
**I want to detect the file size while before the download.**

Or is there another better way to do remote downloading?