# file_put_contents does not return a value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble using file_put_contents.  I thought I could do something like this in laravel/php.

```
$response = new stdClass();
$key = generateKey(); // generates a 32 bit key
$dir = "/mnt/my-usb";
if (file_put_contents($dir . "/" . "key", $key) === true) {
    $response->status = "Fail";
    $response->message = "Some user facing message that describes the error";
    return Response::json($response, 500);
}
```

So I thought I could check the status code file_put_contents and return a good error message.  However, when I step through this code, once it gets to the if statement, if there is a failure, it never enters the if statement.  I'm not sure why.  I've tried it withouth the === true and I get the same results.  I thought that file_put_contents would return some sort of error code that I could look up and create a user facing message, but it just returns automatically and I cannot create a response to send back to the client.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.`

Comment: `file_put_contents` returns `false` in the event of an error. You're testing for `true`.

Comment: Also, does `$key` exist previously as a directory? if not, you need to make that directory using `mkdir()` first, before you can traverse into it and place contents.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check the manual: http://php.net/function.file-put-contents

> This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.

**Meaning:** `file_put_contents` will never return `TRUE`. It will return `false` however, so if you were insistent on using a boolean value then you would need to use:

```
if (file_put_contents($dir . "/" . "key", $key) !== false) {
    // reset of code
}
```

Additionally, there are multiple examples on how to make `file_put_contents` "die silently" (ie testing that the file can be opened if it exists, checking that the folder is writable, etc.)

Comment: This is not allowing me to make a error handling function - it's still just prompting me the error saying "Failed to open stream: No such file or directory" where as I intend of making a specific operation if said upload fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add full path to your file path , like this :

```
/home/Site_Name/public_html/
```